# Spring setLocale

Tags: spring, localization, setlocale

I have a custom `public Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {`  in place that checks for browser language but also checks if the user is authenticated, because if so it will change the locale again based on the settings of the user.

Now I'm trying to add a language selector to an unauthenticated page, by allowing pages to hold the `lang` parameter as explained in the docs. I currently have this:

```
  @Bean
  public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    lci.setParamName("lang");
    return lci;
  }

  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
  }
```

I've noticed, by going to the page with for example `?lang=en` added, that the `setLocale` is being called and here's where I'm stuck. I cannot seem to find out how to actually set the language in this method? I currently have this but this is causing a `StackOverflowError` :

```
  @Override
  public void setLocale(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale) {
    LocaleResolver localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request);
    localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, locale);
  }
```

Can someone help me? :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it in my program, worked withut problems

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    return new SessionLocaleResolver();
}

@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new
            LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
    return localeChangeInterceptor;
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
}
```

After that it should work with just calling it in url with `?lang=en`

Comment: I sadly cannot use the `localeResolver`  as I am implementing `LocaleResolver` in the class, so I am forced to use (and override) `setLocale` where I now have to deal with setting the language myself. But I cannot seem to find how.